# Can I create a bootable HDD partition to install Windows 10?

Tags: boot, partitioning, windows

I will show you the problem. A few days ago I had huge problems on Windows 10, which led me to format and install Windows 7 because at the moment I don't have a 8GB pen drive and due to some problems because of covid I can't even buy one because shops are closed.
But I need to go back to Win10 asap and I got told to try using Linux Ubuntu. So can I create a bootable HDD partition to boot it like a USB pen drive and install Windows 10? If yes, how?

Comment: You can create a bootable HDD partition and have it boot like a USB pen drive, but we support Ubuntu and not windows 10.  I don't see how your question relates to anything on-topic for this site - https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  On trying Ubuntu I'll provide https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/try-ubuntu-before-you-install-it/14014

Comment: @guiverc  Think it might be on topic, since he wants to use Ubuntu to make it bootable.  It takes a bit more information for Ubuntu to make Windows bootable.  I had to google a bit before I could make a USB boot Windows on Ubuntu.

Comment: @guiverc I'm not asking for Win10 support, I'm asking the Ubuntu community how to create a bootable HDD partition. Let's rephrase the question. How do I create a bootable HDD partition in Ubuntu?

Comment: Just wondering if you have googled doing this from Win 7.  Might be easier than installing/using another OS you are not familiar with and having to learn different ways of doing stuff.  Ubuntu is nice, but is not Windows.  We will help you if about Ubuntu.

Comment: One simple answer for many folks: Ask a neighbor to borrow a USB stick for a day or two. Or contact a friend and meet at the market.

Comment: The Windows install procedure should give you the option to create a new partition for Windows 10. Start with Disk Management and shrink your current partition so that you end up with plenty of free space. Use Windows tools when dealing with Windows. Better yet, forget Windows and switch to Ubuntu.